# Character Segmentation from the Image

Tags: image-segmentation

I have made some segments of the image and found the area of interest.I used Sobel vertical detector and morphological operations.

[image]

Now I want to segment all number plate characters from the image which has size [51 165]......How would I do it now?Even segmentation from the whole image was a bit challenging task since my technique does not work if the car(since these are number plates) is too near or far or illumination is poor if somebody has suggestions then please guide me on that.

Sample Image from the dataset

[image]

Comment: Can you post the actual image and your region of interest?

Comment: I have added a sample Image